# Which is the best approach for permutation testing for deep learning models?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, permutation-test

Should I just shuffle my labels and train my model for a certain number of iterations?

The result of permutation testing should give low testing/validation accuracy, right?
Is it necessary to do a permutation test to check the robustness of the deep learning model or 10 fold cross-validation is more than enough?

Machine learning model has `sklearn.model_selection.permutation_test_score`, but deep learning model doesn't have any permutation test functions.

Comment: Why do you think low accuracy required?

Comment: @kevin012 Just a hunch! There is a possibility that the model can learn from the misclassified data right?

Comment: What do you mean by misclassified data?

Comment: @kevin012 By misclassified data I mean I'm shuffling my labels

Comment: Low accuracy doesn't necessary mean the model hasn't learned anything.

Comment: @kevin012 What if with mislabeled data your model gives high accuracy? That's a bad thing right?

Comment: It will affect all the features if you shuffle labels. I'm not sure why you want to shuffle labels. Where did you get this idea?

Comment: @kevin012 I edited my question. Kindly refer to that.

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish? Permutation tests tend to shuffle hundreds, if not thousands, of times. If it takes an hour to train your network, 1000 permutations has you waiting six weeks. If it takes a day to train your network, 1000 permutations has you waiting three years! Perhaps there is away to evaluate what you want to evaluate without having to wait months or years for an answer.

Comment: @Dave I tried 10 fold CV and my validation accuracy is above 95%. Just to check the robustness of my CNN model I wanted to do a permutation testing. But is that necessary?

Comment: I suggest asking a new question about the robustness check where you include more details about what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permutation importance test is to shuffle the feature values. It's not to shuffle the labels. The labels stay fixed all the time. It's to see how much score changed by shuffling the feature values. If the feature is irrelevant, the shuffling will not affect much on the score. But if the feature is important for the model, the shuffling of the feature values will have a big impact on the score.

The score doesn't need to be the accuracy. Accuracy is the score with its own weak point.

The function in sklearn, permutation_test_score is model agnostic. It doesn't depend on any model and it can be used with a deep learning model also. Actually, the test is model agnostic. You may check [this example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/permutation_importance.html#:%7E:text=The%20permutation%20feature%20importance%20is,model%20depends%20on%20the%20feature.) in sklearn documentation.